# How can I change the object pointed to by a group of shared pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a group of shared pointers all pointing to the same object. At a certain moment, I want those pointers to leave the first object (which should be destroied) and all start to point to another object. I have only access to one of those pointers tho, and I have no idea on how to do thay.

With an example:

```
using Ptr = shared_ptr<int>;

void switch_all(Ptr &p) {
    p.reset(new int(14));
}

int main() {
    Ptr a(new int(12));
    Ptr b = a;
    Ptr c(a);

    cout << "Initial situation: " << endl;
    cout << *a.get() << '\t' << a.get() << endl;
    cout << *b.get() << '\t' << b.get() << endl;
    cout << *c.get() << '\t' << c.get() << endl;

    switch_all(c);

    cout << "After reset: " << endl;
    cout << *a.get() << '\t' << a.get() << endl;
    cout << *b.get() << '\t' << b.get() << endl;
    cout << *c.get() << '\t' << c.get() << endl;
}
```

This outputs

```
Initial situation:
12      0xb8797038
12      0xb8797038
12      0xb8797038
After reset:
12      0xb8797038
12      0xb8797038
14      0xb8797468
```

What I want to do is change `switch_all` in a way that the output becomes

```
Initial situation:
12      0xb8797038
12      0xb8797038
12      0xb8797038
After reset:
14      0xb8797468
14      0xb8797468
14      0xb8797468
```

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reset the pointer held by a given `shared_ptr` and have other `shared_ptr` instances automatically pick up the new pointer.  That is simply not how `shared_ptr` works.  When multiple `shared_ptr` instances hold the same pointer, they increment a reference count associated with that pointer.  Resetting one of the `shared_ptr` instances will simply decrement the reference count, leaving the other `shared_ptr` instances with the previous pointer while the reset `shared_ptr` now holds a new pointer.  That is the whole point of `shared_ptr`, to keep a given pointer alive as long as there are active references to it.

What you are asking for requires an extra level of indirection, for example:

```
using UPtr = unique_ptr<int>;

void switch_all(UPtr &p) {
    p.reset(new int(14));
}

int main() {
    UPtr a(new int(12));
    UPtr &b = a;
    UPtr &c = a;

    cout << "Initial situation: " << endl;
    cout << *a.get() << '\t' << a.get() << endl;
    cout << *b.get() << '\t' << b.get() << endl;
    cout << *c.get() << '\t' << c.get() << endl;

    switch_all(c);

    cout << "After reset: " << endl;
    cout << *a.get() << '\t' << a.get() << endl;
    cout << *b.get() << '\t' << b.get() << endl;
    cout << *c.get() << '\t' << c.get() << endl;
}
```

Or

```
using UPtr = unique_ptr<int>;

void switch_all(UPtr *p) {
    p->reset(new int(14));
}

int main() {
    UPtr a(new int(12));
    UPtr *b = &a;
    UPtr *c = &a;

    cout << "Initial situation: " << endl;
    cout << *a.get() << '\t' << a.get() << endl;
    cout << *(b->get()) << '\t' << b->get() << endl;
    cout << *(c->get()) << '\t' << c->get() << endl;

    switch_all(c);

    cout << "After reset: " << endl;
    cout << *a.get() << '\t' << a.get() << endl;
    cout << *(b->get()) << '\t' << b->get() << endl;
    cout << *(c->get()) << '\t' << c->get() << endl;
}
```

Comment: I hoped there was a way to change the pointer stored by the manager object, so that all shared pointers which point to that manager object now point to a different managed object. Guess I'll have to design a shared_ptr class from scratch.